# How does the name end up getting capitalized?

Tags: python

```
###  Greeting people more formally  ###

def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()

# This is an infinite loop!
while True:
    print("\nPlease tell me your name:")
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")
    f_name = input("first name: ")
    if f_name == 'q':
        break
    l_name = input("Last name: ")
    if l_name == 'q':
        break

    formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)
    print(f"\nHello, {formatted_name}!")
```

```
Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
first name: john
Last name: doe

Hello, John Doe!

Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
first name: 
Last name: q

***Repl Closed***
```

I am a beginner when it comes to coding.
My question is, why is the name... capitalized?

Im confused at the lower part of the first code

The inputs end up under the values (`f_name` and `l_name`)

`formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)`
inputs go into the function...
the `get_formatted_name` fuction gets thrown up and applied in the earlier code?

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()
```

this one?
ends up being returned to python as the `full_name.title()`
and that ends up being what `formatted_name` equals... right?
because `full_name.title()` came as a result of the function `get_formatted_name`
and `get_formatted_name` equals `formatted_name`

therefore that is the process of how the name gets capitalized right?

sooooo**....**
have an input, function sends the input to the earlier function, function processes and refines the input and returns it back into the code, whatever is returned is made equal to `formatted_name`.... and then ends up being printed out... yes?

**does that mean** that `f_name` serves as an input for `first_name` in this case?
same for `l_name`? I think that is what threw me off..

This code is from a book called
Python Crash Course 2nd Edition
page 141

Comment: The `.title()` function on a `str` object (string) cases the capitalisation.  Here: `full_name.title()`. If you remove the `.title()` function call, only the concatenated string will be returned. **As an experiment**, change `.title()` to `.upper()`.

Comment:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Answer (score 1):

Short, but harsh:
https://google.com/search?q=string+title+python+3+docs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=title#str.title

Longer:

str.title()

> Return a titlecased version of the string where **words** start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase.